# Push notifications or polling in a phonegap app?

Tags: cordova, push

Any advice would be great. I am developing a phonegap app. The user sends a request to the server and the server then needs to send updates on the request in real time. Would it be best to have the app poll the server or to push notifications to the app?

Comment: Depends on your usecase. Please be more specific!

Comment: Sorry, I'll try be more specific. The user of the app books an appointment, the appointment details are posted to the server from the webview in phonegap app and are then saved on the server. Then the details are displayed on a website (i use sockets.io for this), the staff member then confirms the appointment and a notification is sent back to the app user. So in this case,(wait time could be a couple of minutes until a response is sent) is it better to have the app poll the server or wait for a push notification?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your case.

If you need to send specific updates to a user according to his/her request only, then you should use polling server.

However, if you need to send the updates the user in real time (ex: notifying the user of new messages or events without the need to actually open the application), then you should use push notification. To do this with PhoneGap, it requires a third party plugin. I would like to recommend you to try [Monaca](http://monaca.mobi/en/). It is a cross-platform app development with PhoneGap using HTML5 and Javascript. Sending push notification with Monaca is very simple. Please refer to [their documentation](http://docs.monaca.mobi/en/manual/backend/push/#push-notification-manual) regarding push notification.

I hope this help answering your question somehow. Cheer!

Comment: Thanks Tamura, i found the PushPlugin-https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin but never seen that one so i'll check it out, thanks a lot:)

Answer (score -1):

You can do asynchronous ajax calls using jQuery or javascript to a web api or a simple post to a server.  Obviously with these call you can data back which you can process.

```
//assuming your are using jQuery in your phonegap app something as simple as:

$('body').on('click', '#SOME_BUTTON_ID', function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    $.post( "URL_TO_POST_TO", { DATA_TO_SEND },  function( data ) {
        //DO SOMETHING WITH THE DATA YOU GET BACK
        $(".result").html(data);
    });
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Push notifications are one-way from the server to the app but it will notify your device even if the app is not active.  however with phonegap this requires some third party plugins.   There are some on the phonegap/cordova web site.

Comment: This answer is pretty useless without a plugin that allows you to poll the server without running the app entirely. Could you provide a way to find such third-party plugins? If you could, You'd have my upvote.